# Redshift: Max items within "IN clause"?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a query like:

```
SELECT count(id), pro.country_code 
FROM profiles AS pro 
WHERE id IN (SELECT profile_id FROM reports) 
GROUP BY pro.country_code;
```

**My questions:**

How many items can you use in a Redshift IN CLAUSE? Storing the actual ids instead of the sub-sql statement has got to be faster for performing that outer query each time, right?

Comment: There is no limitation for the number of items returned by the sub-select. At least not in Postgres and as Amazon is a fork (albeit from a really old version) there shouldn't be any limitation as well.

Answer (score 4):

From what I know, there is no limit but if you going to bring a lot data you can use exists.

```
SELECT count(id), 
pro.country_code 
FROM profiles AS pro 
WHERE exists (SELECT profile_id FROM reports where pro.id=reports.profile_id) 
GROUP BY pro.country_code;
```

It should be much more faster

Also you can use intersect instead of in

Comment: According to this post, the execution is identical: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50800120/where-exists-vs-in-in-amazon-redshift

Answer (score 1):

As "user" already stated, your best performance will be with a WHERE EXISTS clause and subquery. Since you mentioned performance as an important consideration, I should also point out that the more important performance factor would like be your table distribution. In order for this to perform well, you'll want to double check that both tables have the column "profile_id" as the distribution key and that both tables have declared the column using the same data type.